# jQuery - Ajax to jsRender failed

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsrender

I have a function called UpdateBoatTable, which is supposted to update a HTML Template via jsRender. The function looks like following:

```
$.fn.UpdateBoatTable = function() 
{ 
$.ajax({
    url: "backend/boat.php?a=show",
    datatype: "json",
    success: function(data) 
    {
        alert(data);
        $("#BoatList").html
        (
            $("#BoatTemplate").render(data)
        );
    }
});
}
```

The MessageBox (alert(data)) is returning the following value:

```
[{"BoatID":"2","RegNo":"Registration Number","BoatName":"Boatname","BoatType":"Type"}]
```

But rendering the data to a template fails.

**If i am going to hard code the json data, it works...**

```
$.fn.UpdateBoatTable = function() 
{ 
$.ajax({
    url: "backend/boat.php?a=show",
    datatype: "json",
    success: function(data) 
    {
        var data = [{"BoatID":"2","RegNo":"Registration Number","BoatName":"Boatname","BoatType":"Type"}];
        alert(data);
        $("#BoatList").html
        (
            $("#BoatTemplate").render(data)
        );
    }
});
}
```

Can you tell me why it is only working if it is hardcoded?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typo, `datatype: "json",` should be `dataType: "json",`